Time Complexity of Memoized Function and Rigorous Proof Approaches
Suppose we have the following toy code that does nothing:
@cache
def fn(i, j):
  if i > j:
    return 0
  
  for k in range(i, j + 1):
    fn(i, k - 1)
    fn(k + 1, j)

It will be initially invoked with the call fn(0, n), where n is some integer. My question has to do with a rigorous proof of time complexity. A naive and nonrigorous analysis may assert that we are, at maximum, going to have n^2 states (because there are (n^2 / 2 valid call combinations), and each call with require, at worst, an O(n) operation. Therefore, n^2 total calls multiplied by an O(n) operation for each call gives us O(n^3).
While this way of analyzing recursion time complexity can sometimes informally work, see my other question. Namely, this approach would lead you astray in the case of meth_2. Indeed, it can be shown meth_2 will have n + 1 levels, where each level has roughly nChoosei calls, where i represents the given recursion level (indexed from 0). Summing calls across levels would leave you with 2^n total calls, each performing an O(n) operation. Thus, this informal method of computing time complexity would lead you to believe that meth_2 has a time complexity of O(2^n * n) when, in reality, it is O(2^n). I say all of this to ask: How can I rigorously and appropriately compute the time complexity of the memoized function above? More generally, what is a rigorous, fool-proof approach to computing any recursive function's time complexity?
